# Is there a way to select the eyedropper tool while typing?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, shortcuts, eyedropper

Is there a way to use the eyedropper tool while typing?

I cant' type "I" to select it, because that just inserts the letter i.

Answer (score 3):

**TLDR: alt-eyedropper applies the copied style like a paintbrush**

This answer is actually *easier* than what you're asking for -- you don't have to navigate to get to the next text you want to format.

Suppose that you want to **use the eyedropper to modify parts of a text block but not the whole block**. For example, to change the font on a bunch of different header lines or to change a bunch of words to italic.

You can’t activate the eyedropper while you’re editing, but **you can get the same utility using the option key**, applying it to specific words or phrases, while skipping around the document.

You don’t have to navigate to get to the text you want to format.

**Using the option key:**

- **deselect** everything
- **press i** for the eyedropper
- **click on the text** with the formatting you want to copy
- **press alt/option** (the icon changes orientation)
- **drag the eyedropper over the word or text** you want to format, as if you were selecting it.

**Note:** It's frustrating that the text selection is invisible, but text formatting is updated as desired.

Comment: Oh wow! Solved my problem. Has Adobe mentioned it on their site? Google search shows nothing.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>ESC</kbd> key then the <kbd>i</kbd> key.

Because the Eyedropper Tool has no function when editing text, you have to exit the text editing mode first. The <kbd>ESC</kbd> will do that.

If the intent is to use the Eyedropper Tool while still in text editing mode, I don't think that's possible. Any tool switch results in leaving text editing mode.

Comment: You can use the eyedropper tool while editing, I do it all the time. You just have to click on it in the tool palette.

Comment: @AndrewSwift Forgive me but you are mistaken. As soon as you click the Eyedropper tool.. you *exit* text editing mode -- as in you can no longer add or delete type in the string of point or area text.. you've left text editing. Please read again.. I stated "text editing" not merely "editing".

Comment: https://vimeo.com/267962783 Illustrator CC 2017 on a Mac.

Comment: @AndrewSwift fair enough. I was mistaken. `:)` I've honestly never even thought about using the eyedropper that way. I mean, that's what Paragraph and Character Styles are for. `:)`